# Are there any video players with variable speed playback?

Tags: video

I am looking for a video player that can play videos on my SD card with variable speed playback

**Related Questions**

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/comparision-of-video-players-for-android

Comment: Looking forward VLC player is released for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dice player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.inisoft.mediaplayer.trial&hl=en) can go up to 1.8X.

Comment: A link to the app in the Market would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm. No. At least not that i know of.

I tried VPlayer, Rockplayer, the stock player, iMplayer. None of that has control over the play speed.

If i find out I get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some: VLC for Android, BSPlayer, Dice Player

With BSPlayer you are able to speed up youtube as well if you're interested, as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84446/possible-to-play-youtube-videos-at-2x-speed) (though as of now, bsplayer shows 'not available in your country' in my app store (USA), hope you can get it)

Answer (score 0):

I can do this nicely on N900 (Maemo 5) using mplayer, but nothing on the Android side yet for fast playback of videos.