# Play video with 2x speed in MX player kindly help

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, video, mx-player

The problem is that I have to watch some MIT OCW video lectures on my mobile device and I'm using MX player to watch these videos. The catch is that I want to watch 50 minute lecture in 25-30 minute but I seem to find no way out to do this on android. I know I can play those videos on VLC media player on a laptop at 2x speed but the problem is that I don't have a laptop.

Suggest me what can I do. How can I watch them at 2x speed?

**P.S. I use an android device version 4.1 jellybean. Also I'm not streaming the videos I have already downloaded the videos and now want to watch them offline.**

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Comment: MX player offers tweaking play speed. When playing a video, tap the three dots line -> Play -> Speed -> configure it. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Firelord yeah! tried it right now but it shows something different than what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that when you move two fingers up and down the left side of the screen (like when you adjust brightness, but with two fingers) the playback speed adjusts accordingly.

Comment: I am unable to verify it. Are you sure that it is in MX Player?

Comment: Perhaps you should add that this Gesture may be disabled via the controls menu.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MX Player, but other apps also let you control speed, you could give them a try. Here are some: VLC for Android, BSPlayer, Dice Player

With BSPlayer you are able to speed up youtube as well if you're interested, as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84446/possible-to-play-youtube-videos-at-2x-speed) (though as of now, bsplayer shows 'not available in your country' in my app store (USA), hope you can get it)

Answer (score 0):

When you play a Video with [MX Player](https://mxplayerdownloads.com/), click on the dots for menu there you will find playing speed. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Please  do  a proper  research  before writing  an answer  here.